# How to query a database for several table?

Tags: android, sql, database, android-sqlite

I have problem with databases. Namely, how to retrieve a query so that the query method looks at several arrays?

For examply, I have a databse table: People, Car, Job, Weather etc.

```
SQLiteOpenHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
databaseHelper.query("People",
   new String[]{"_id", "NAME"},
   "FAVORITE = 1", 
    null, null, null, null, null);
```

So how to put more than one table? How to get "_id" and "NAME" from these data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use rawquery to write sql statements(select * from table1,table2 where col1=col2)

Comment: Thanks, I just thought that I need to use this method.